# X11 forwarding over ssh

Tags: ssh, x11, xephyr

I used to log into a remote server on our corporate network using Xephyr and ssh using the following command

```
Xephyr :0 -ac -br -screen 950x540 | xterm -bg black -fg white -display :0 -e ssh -Yf jidicula@lxsim gnome-session &
```

where :0 is the display from ENV. This used to work for me, however I got upgraded to a new mac pro machine and this no longer works for me. Would someone be able to help me with this. I understand what this is doing and I made sure to have Xephyr and XQuartz on my new machine so I am kinda baffled as to why this no longer works.

Comment: Exactly what did change? Were you using a Mac too before the Pro one?

Comment: yes I was..I had the older mac pro and the os x was 10.6 and the one I have now is 10.9 ("mavericks"). My old machine had an xquartz from 2 years ago. those are the only obvious ones I can think of. I went into my ssh config file and turned on X11 forwarding

Comment: this command works but it crashes half of the time and i dont trust it to run stuff that takes days on the cluster `Xnest -geometry 800x600 :1& DISPLAY=:1 ssh -Y`

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve... You are running a nested X server (Xephyr) locally and forwarding X11 from the (network) server into it?

Comment: i dont know all the right terminology but I am essentially trying to remote desktop into a linux server using an xserver. i think this guy might be able to explain it a little bit better. http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/xephyr.html

Comment: I don't understand the original command. `xterm` doesn't read from standard input, so why are you piping the output of `Xephyr` to it? The problem may simply be a timing issue -- `xterm` may be trying to open the `Xephyr` display before it's set up. Try running `Xephyr <options> &` and then `xterm`.

Comment: Question: does the xterm window open in the first place? I.e. is your problem with `xterm` or with the forwarding to the remote server?

Answer (score 1):

so it turns out the issue was due to Xquartz 2.7.5. As soon as I went back to Xquartz 2.7.4 all the old commands started working. So if you are interested in X11 forwarding on a Mac and want to use Xephyr...make sure you are using 2.7.4